# How to instantiate a class that is declared in a C# DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, instance

I have a DLL written in C#. In this DLL there is a class that is defined.
Let's assume that the code of this DLL is :

```
namespace unloadableDLL
{
    public class DivisionClass
    {
        public /*static*/ long Division(long x, long y)
        {
            // We deliberately do not use a try catch to catch divide by 0 exceptions
            return (x / y);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to load dynamically this DLL in a test program. I need to see what happens if I divide by zero in the two following cases :
1) DLL is loaded directly (without using an AppDomain)
2) DLL is not loaded directly, an AppDomain is created first and then it loads the DLL.

I'm completely new in C#, by new I mean I've started less than 4 hours ago but I have a C++ background.

My problem is that in my test program, I need to instanciate a DivisionClass Object but this one is declared only in the DLL.
=> Resolved

My test program is

```
class Program
    {
        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load the DLL
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to load unloadableDLL");
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("./unloadableDLL.dll");
            unloadableDLL.DivisionClass divisionObject = (unloadableDLL.DivisionClass)a.CreateInstance("unloadableDLL.DivisionClass");
            long number = divisionObject.Division(8, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
```

I don't know what but the compilers keeps telling me that Static member unloadableDLL.DivisionClass.Division(lon, long) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a typename instead.

Thank you all

Comment: do you mean calling DivisionClass.Division(x, y) which actually doesn't instantiate the DivisionClass, since it's a static method?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please note that you don't need to create an instance as `Division` is a static method.

Comment: call directly from your project reference for.eg `unloadableDLL.DivisionClass.Division(100,10)`. Since it is static method you don't need to create an instance.

Comment: I think his bigger issue is how do use the static class without an explicit project reference to its containing dll.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that Divison was static. Let's consider that it is not, the code is now :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load into a separate AppDomain an execute the method from there - use reflection as in the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298913/static-fields-in-appdomain). It does get involved as is typically a more advanced C# topic but the code is fairly boilerplate and for a man with C++ knowledge it shouldn't present problems.

For a direct call then follow the methods outlined above - i.e. reference the dll in your project and instantiate through code as per Oded (who has deleted his answer unfortunately so reproducing below)

```
DivisionClass.Division(1, 2)
```

**EDIT**

If the methods are not static

Invoking a method via reflection

```
  Assembly myAssembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("myPath\\Assembly1.dll");     
  Type myType = myAssembly1.GetType("MyClass");      
  object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);     
  myType.Invoke("myMethodName", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, myObject, null);
```

In a separate App Domain adds to the complexity - see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx).

Also I don't think your Division class will work as is. To call across app domains you need to employ some kind of serialisation for your classes or inherit the class from MarshalByRefObject - see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206961/sharing-data-between-appdomains). Given that this looks like a proof of concept type of thing/a ground up implementation of your class then MarshalByRefObject would be you best bet - easiest i think. That said executing across AppDomains can get fiddly.

Invoking a method via instaniation in code

```
DivisionClass divisor = new DivisionClass()
divisor.Division(1,2)
```

Comment: I made a mistake. Let's assume that the method "Division" is not static.