# Static Variable Instances and AppDomains, what is happening?

Tags: c#, variables, static, instance, appdomain

I have

```
public static class A
{
   public static string ConnString;
}

[Serializable]
public class Test{
   // Accesing A's field;
   public string ConnString{get{return A.ConnString;}set{A.ConnString=value;}}
}

void Main()
{
   A.ConnString = "InitialString"; // I set A.ConnString in the current domain

   var newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("DomNew");
   Test TObj = newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Test).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Test).FullName) as Test ;

   TObj.ConnString = "NewDomainString"; // It is supposed to set A.ConnString in the newDomain aka a different instance of A.ConnString

   // Here it is supposed to print two different values
   Console.WriteLine(A.ConnString);  // "InitialString"
   Console.WriteLine(TObj.ConnString); // "NewDomainString"
}
```

But NO! The two WriteLines, print out the same value "NewDomainString"!
WHY???

this code

```
TObj.ConnString = "NewDomainString"
```

is supposed to change the string in the newly created domain, but it seems they both refer to the same instance!

Why, what is happening here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298913/static-fields-in-appdomain

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: You are right John! Newbie here :) I'm learning! Thanks!

Comment: Daryal you are right. My search was limited to "static variables" and I missed the "static fields" part :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are only two ways for a class to be accessible from another AppDomain- one is is the class is `[Serializable]`, as your Test class is, the other is if the class inherits from [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).  Because your class is Serializable, a copy of it is created for every cross-AppDomain call.  So the `Test` that the main appdomain gets when you call...

```
Test TObj = newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Test).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Test).FullName) as Test;
```

is actually not the Test instance that was created in the "DomNew" AppDomain- it is a copy local to the "main" AppDomain, and therefore references the static variables from the "main" AppDomain.

If you want `Test` to exhibit the behavior that you expect, make it inherit from MarshalByRefObject instead of being Serializable.

Comment: Nit: there is actually a 3rd way. marshal by bleed  http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,884ca8af-76fb-4753-a9d9-d12075dabb51.aspx

Comment: @JaredPar yikes, yeah...  Makes me wince.

Comment: Thanx, that was actually what I was looking for. It happened that I found the answer on my own shortly after I made the question. For some reason I didn't try the MarshalByRef inheritance, though I knew there was such a thing. I think i was mislead by an answer in another forum saying that these two ways (Serializable Attribute, and MarshalByRef inheritance) were identical.

Though, I think that if Serializable Attirbute is a way to make a "local" copy of the class, you don't actually access the object from another Domain, right? Is it just to "read" an object's state from another domain?

Answer (score 12):

You marked your Test class as Serializable. This is wrong. You should have derived from MarshalByRef. Otherwise TObj will just be a local copy in the current AppDomain.