# How to prevent property overriding when running multiple app instances on single AppDomain?

Tags: c#

I have an application that is running multiple instances of itself on a single AppDomain, it is intended this way.

I have a couple of **static properties** that are initialized at the beginning and each is unique for the instance running it.

Now when I run first instance, everything is fine, but when I run second instance, it overrides properties of first instance.

How could I prevent that?

I can't use singleton pattern in such situation.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806372/static-variable-instances-and-appdomains-what-is-happening relevant?

Answer (score 0):

In `c#` a `static` property is intended to be *shared* between all instances of the same class, regardless how many instances there are.
Take as an example `DateTime.Now`

If the properties are intended to be unique between intances of the class you shouldn't use the `static`modifier.